# How to add delay into lambda expression near method which returns value?

Tags: java, lambda

Sorry for, perhaps, obvious question, but i can't add delay into  lambda expression. I tried:

```
Callable<int> task = () -> {TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1); concurrentHashMap.get(treeNum).getApples()};
```

and IDE shows "Missing return statement".
How to add delay?

Comment: Well have you tried *adding* a `return` statement? You're calling `getApples()` but not doing anything with the result. The compiler is giving you just about the strongest hint it can here... your lambda expression is meant to return an `int`, but currently it doesn't. Imagine that code within a method returning `int`, and basically the same error message - how would you fix it?

Comment: Added, but yesterday it didn't work. Now works. =) Oops.

Comment: I'm sure yesterday it would have worked, but either you didn't save, or some similar error.

Answer (score 1):

Lambda expressions can be written like this `p -> inlineMethod()`, ie with an implicit return statement only when there is only one statement.

Otherwise, you must have a code block like this `p -> { [...]; return null; }`. In this case, you must add explicitly the return statement (one or more) into the block.